# During login, why does it take more time to give an error message, than to login?

Tags: login

When I login after boot, or maybe after a idle time, I am presented with a login box. If I enter the incorrect password, it takes a longer time to verify, and give the error message, than entering the correct password, and getting logged in. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a delay when entering a wrong password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474080/why-is-there-a-delay-when-entering-a-wrong-password)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because this makes brute-force guessing passwords more time-consuming and therefore less likely. See also [1](http://ohioloco.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9657390&postcount=3)

Comment: This is correct. The login screen (GDM) communicates with Linux-PAM to check user credentials. If the user fails to authenticate, Linux-PAM [waits a random amount of time](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/old/pam_appl-3.html#the-failure-delay-function) before sending its response back to GDM.

Comment: @ændrük The link is not working. I have the following revised link from web.archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20081008011541/http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/old/pam_appl-3.html#the-failure-delay-function