# Why is there a delay when entering a wrong password?

Tags: password

When entering the right password the application or the OS (no specific application, pretty much everywhere) accepts this immediately, but when entering a wrong password there is a slight delay of 1-2 seconds. Why is that?

Answer (score 10):

The delay is to slow down cracking attempts made by automated software. Without a delay cracking attempts would run much faster.

Documentation: See [man pam_fail_delay](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/pam_fail_delay.3.html)

> RATIONALE
>
> ```
>    It is often possible to attack an authentication scheme by exploiting
>    the time it takes the scheme to deny access to an applicant user. In
>    cases of short timeouts, it may prove possible to attempt a brute force
>    dictionary attack -- with an automated process, the attacker tries all
>    possible passwords to gain access to the system. In other cases, where
>    individual failures can take measurable amounts of time (indicating the
>    nature of the failure), an attacker can obtain useful information about
>    the authentication process. These latter attacks make use of procedural
>    delays that constitute a covert channel of useful information.
>
>    To minimize the effectiveness of such attacks, it is desirable to
>    introduce a random delay in a failed authentication process. Preferable
>    this value should be set by the application or a special PAM module.
>    Standard PAM modules should not modify the delay unconditional.
> ```

Comment: Is there anything related in official documentations?

Comment: Yes, I can link a few - https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/oracle_linux_5/2015-06-05/finding/V-768 and https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_fail_delay