# Why does ubuntu take a long time to figure out that the password inputted is wrong?

Tags: password

I am not sure if this is a problem specific to my device. All of my friends face it too. At the login page or at the authentication alert for connecting to WiFi or when I'm granting root access, basically every time I input a password, if the password inputted is wrong my device takes unusually long time to process it (around 2-3 seconds). However, if the password inputted is correct it processes it immediately. If this is not an issue specific to my device, why is this the case?

Comment: It's a good security feature. If it provided an immediate response then anyone trying to guess your password can work more quickly. Adding a one or two second delay vastly increases the time it would take to brute force your password

Comment: This feature can be configured by changing `FAIL_DELAY` in `/etc/login.defs`. Type `man login.defs` for more info.

Comment: @Will Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I think @girardengo's would be a better answer than mine. My comment explains the reasoning but his explains the setting to change it.

Comment: @Will To be fair a combination of both yours and girardengo's comments would be even better as an answer.

Comment: *I'm using ubuntu 15.04*... You shouldn't because that release is EoL. Please install (or upgrade to) a supported release.

Comment: True enough, and since @girardengo has more rep than me I'll steal this one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a delay when entering a wrong password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474080/why-is-there-a-delay-when-entering-a-wrong-password)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an intentional security feature to prevent brute forcing of passwords on your system, via SSH, local login or other means.

You can customise it, but be careful modifying PAM configuration as you can lock yourself out of your system.  I suggest keeping an editor of the file open in 1 tab, and test out sudo / SSH login in another to make sure it's working.

Modifying /etc/login.defs used to be how it is done but that is no longer used (even in 15.04 vivid, which is no longer supported for at least a year, you should upgrade to 16.04).  There are two steps, first we need to add "nodelay" to pam_unix's options in /etc/pam.d/common-auth.  On my system it looks like this with nodelay added, but I would just add it to whatever configuration your system already has.

> auth  [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure nodelay

Then we need to add at least a small delay back in.  This is important for security even if it's small like half a second it's much better than "infinite speed".  We can do that with the pam_faildelay module.   Add this line to the file *before* the pam_unix.so line

> auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=500000

For more information, check the manpages for pam_unix and pam_faildelay.  I am not an expert in PAM, so I recommend reading up further about it if you intend to make this change on anything more than a local laptop or desktop.  I would be wary of the effects of this on public internet facing systems without further research.

Answer (score 6):

It's a good security feature. If it provided an immediate response then anyone trying to guess your password can work more quickly. Adding a one or two second delay vastly increases the time it would take to brute force your password

As girardengo added, this feature can be configured by changing `FAIL_DELAY` in `/etc/login.defs`. Type `man login.defs` for more info.

Also, as CelticWarrior pointed out, 15.04 is no longer supported, you should upgrade to a supported release. I usually stick with the long term support versions to cut down on the amount of major upgrades I have to do